# In React Scroll event listener shows error on scroll

Tags: html, reactjs, scroll, navbar, addeventlistener

```
const nav1=document.querySelector('.navbar');
 window.addEventListener('scroll',
      function ()
         {
            if(window.scrollY>70)
             {
                nav1.classList.add('new_nav');
             }
            else if (window.scrollY < 69) 
             {
            nav1.classList.remove('new_nav');
         }
     }
```

Im trying this code in React App.js file, if i scroll down it shows error like "nav1 is NULL".It worked when it was a html,js file.

If i scroll the class file need to change.

Answer (score 0):

events are handled a bit differently in ReactJS.I'll suggest you read through React docs as well [ReactJS Docs](https://react.dev/learn)

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const navRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const nav1 = navRef.current;
    const onScroll = (event) => {
      if (window.scrollY > 70) {
        nav1.classList.add("new_nav");
      } else if (window.scrollY < 69) {
        nav1.classList.remove("new_nav");
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav className="App" ref={navRef}>
      navigation
    </nav>
  );
}
```

I've attached a solution here [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-fire-x8h7j6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for the rply bro.Its shows error "navRef is not defined".

Comment: try to follow the example in codesandbox... I guess you miss something while copying the code. Read through the code line by line to see where you miss the definition, propably you miss this line const navRef = useRef(null);